# Putting Data onto a map with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to layer data points onto a map for a project. My API call for the map is working and I can plot my data but I cannot seem to get both down at the same time.

The code I'm using is

```
x <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -113.811241, lat= 52.268112), 
                   zoom = 7, scale = 1, maptype ='terrain') + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude,  color = Answer), 
                      data = High, size = 0.5) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

I keep getting the error message

> Incompatible methods ("Ops.raster", "+.gg") for "+"Error in get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -113.811241, lat = 52.268112),  :
> non-numeric argument to binary operator

I've checked all data types and everything I am inputting is numeric. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You seeem to have left off the `ggmap` step. Try adding `%>% ggmap()` after the `get_googlemap()` and before the `+ geom_point()`.

Comment: wow, that was a simple fix. Thanks for the help man.